# main.c:36:9: error: array size missing in ‘num’ int num[]; Why am I getting error for array size although i have given array size in code?

Tags: arrays, c, declaration, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>

int removeduplicates(int arr[],int n){
    int j=0;
    int temp[15];
    if(n==0 || n==1){
         return n;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        if(arr[i]!=arr[i+1]){
            temp[j++]=arr[i];
        }
        temp[j++]=arr[n-1];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
         arr[i]=temp[i];
    }
    return j;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    int num[];
    num[]= {1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5};
    n= sizeof(num)/sizeof(num[0]);

    n=removeduplicates(num,n);
    printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Here in this question I was writing a code to remove duplicates from a sorted array. But I am getting the following error although I defined the array size and although I provided the array size.

```
main.c:36:9: error: array size missing in ‘num’
     int num[];
         ^~~
main.c:37:9: error: expected expression before ‘]’ token
     num[]= {1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5};
```

Comment: You can't just guess the syntax or try to learn it by trial & error. You need to actually study the chapter about arrays in your beginner-level C book.

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet

```
int num[];
num[]= {1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5};
```

is syntactically incorrect.

Instead write

```
int num[] = {1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5};
```

Also within the function this declaration with the magic number 15

```
int temp[15];
```

and this statement

```
   temp[j++]=arr[n-1];
```

in the substatement of this for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
   
   if(arr[i]!=arr[i+1]){
       temp[j++]=arr[i];
   }
   temp[j++]=arr[n-1];
}
```

do not make a sense.

To remove duplicates there is no need to define an auxiliary array.

The function can be written for example the following way as shwon in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t removeduplicates( int arr[], size_t  n )
{
    size_t m = 0;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i != n; )
    {
        if ( m != i )
        {
            arr[m] = arr[i];
        }
        
        ++m;
        
        while ( ( ++i != n && arr[i] == arr[i-1] ) );
    }
    
    return m;
}
 
int main(void) 
{
    int num[]= { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( num ) / sizeof( *num );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i != N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", num[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t m = removeduplicates( num, N );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i != m; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", num[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 
1 2 3 4 5
```